# Searching for strings from column and creating new column in spark dataframe with results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have dataframe consisting of columns. I need to check the http link and stored the value code in new column using spark dataframe.

```
 Dataframe :  
colA    colB    ColC    colD  
A       B       C       a1.abc.com/823659)   a1.abc.com/823521)  
B       C       D       go.xyz.com/?LinkID=226971   a1.abc.com/823521)  
C       D       E       a1.abc.com/?LinkID=226971   go.xyz.com/?LinkID=226975  
Required Output:  
colA    colB    ColC    colD                                                   ColE  
A       B       C       a1.abc.com/823659)   a1.abc.com/823521)                823659,823521  
B       C       D       go.xyz.com/?LinkID=226971   a1.abc.com/823521)         226971,823521  
C       D       E       a1.abc.com/?LinkID=226971   go.xyz.com/?LinkID=226975  226971,226975  

df.withColumn("colE", regexp_extract(col("colD"), 'regex', ".com"
```

I have tried using regexp_extract, dont the pattern in not getting matched. Could you please help to get the required output.

Comment: Need to define your requirements better. Ambiguous as it stands.

Comment: I want the new column from the existing column having the match and storing the the value in new column(as per the Required Output colE)

Comment: That's still ambiguous. Is it only numeric data? Or can you have after .com also non-numeric of interest.

Comment: Modded the answer.

Comment: And now the answer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, run this, you can add the other columns, and I am not sure of your string, but assume spaces. Added to the original answer.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("A", "a1.abc.com/823659)   a1.abc.com/823521 a1.abc.com/9999)"), ("B", "go.xyz.com/?LinkID=226971   a1.abc.com/823521)")   ).toDF("col1", "col2")
val df2 = df.withColumn("col3", split(col("col2"), " "))
val df3 = df2.select($"col1", $"col2", array_except($"col3", array(lit(""))).as("col3"))
val df4 = df3.withColumn("xyz", explode($"col3")).withColumn("leng", length($"xyz")) 
// Get values to right of .com
val df5 = df4.withColumn("xyz2", substring_index($"xyz", ".com", -1))
val df6 = df5.withColumn("col4", regexp_replace(df5("xyz2"), "[^0-9]", "")  )
val df7 = df6.select($"col1", $"col4")
val dfres = df7.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_list(col("col4")).as("col2"))
dfres.show(false)
```

returns *on my data*:

```
+----+----------------------+
|col1|col2                  |
+----+----------------------+
|B   |[226971, 823521]      |
|A   |[823659, 823521, 9999]|
+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom for the help, but I need to search the  string "abc.com" from column and the code with abc.com has to been put in other column.                                     Eg. abc.com  823659,823521

Comment: Pretty sure that works. I just did not do all cols, but the principle are provided.

Comment: Will add tonight. Gotcha

Comment: Modded the answer.